# Remove letters with accent or ñ in python from a csv file

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I have a project where I have two files one remove.csv with special characters like letters with accent or "ñ" and I have to find these letters in the text an replace them with another character.
I'm having issues with encoding.

Can you help, please?
Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and include which version of python you are using. Python 3 is much better at dealing with CSV files with encodings. Also... what should the non-ascii characters be replaced with?

Comment: The simplest quick&dirty answer is usually to use an encoding error handler—`s.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii')`. I can’t really give you a better answer when you haven’t given us a [mcve], or anything at all beyond “having issues with encoding”, but hopefully that’s at least enough to get you started experimenting or searching to find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try `s.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii')` for a quick and dirty way like abarnert said, but you will need to post code and a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better answers! Saying that you have issues without us knowing anything about your code is hard for us to help.